# Eclipse modal dialogs disappear under Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm having a strange issue with the Eclipse IDE on Ubuntu.

When opening a modal dialog in eclipse and then switching to another tool, like my browser, and then switching back again, the modal dialog I had open seems to disappear.

Is there any way to get the dialog back into focus? This is quite annoying when the dialogs are modal. So far, the only way I can get it working again is to exit the IDE, and then open it again.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Same here. I have seen it with different dialogs (Git commit, Installation details).  THe only workaround is to kill Eclipse, as you can no longer interact with the application.

Comment: same here! Any updates on this?
I have also to kill my eclipse, since the modal dialog seems to be anythere but cannot be seen and so my eclipse is blocked

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK have the same issue with search dialog (and only this one, it seems) after updating  ZendStudio to 13.0.1 (Eclipse 4.5.1) on ubuntu 14.04 - seems problem with eclipse rather than ubuntu itself

Comment: Lodge a bug in eclipse bugzilla. http://bugs.eclipse.org/

Comment: maybe the same issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/569574/ubuntu-eclipse-window-disappears

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Unity and is not limited to Eclipse - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1584885.

Unfortunately the only workaround as mentioned in the comments is to close Eclipse - right-click on the Eclipse icon in the taskbar and select 'Quit' (you might have to do it more than once until Eclipse responds).

You could also upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 which features GNOME instead of Unity.